# Gridview Width and Alignment

Tags: html, css, asp.net, gridview

I have fixed header table and a gridview control. I tried a lot to fix each column heading under each column but couldn't succeed. When I see in inspect, it shows me header ID width 50px which is correct. But it shows boundfield EmpID width 66px which is wrong. Similarly for header Employee shows 150px is correct but for boundfield EmpName showing 200px. How to fix width and align each column with header and gridview result?

```
<div style="height: 30px; margin: 0; padding: 0">
    <table id="tblHeader" class=""
        style="background-color: #336666; color: white; border-collapse: collapse; height: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left;width: 50px">
                <span>ID</span>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:left;width: 150px">
                <span>Employee</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div style="height: 360px; overflow: auto;">
    <asp:GridView ID="grdEmp" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        OnRowCommand="grdEmp_RowCommand" ShowHeader="false"
        GridLines="None" Font-Size="Small">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpID" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpName">
                <ItemStyle CssClass="RowStyle150"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
        <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
    </asp:GridView>
</div>

.RowStyle50 {
    text-align:left;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    width: 50px !important;
}

.RowStyle150 {
    text-align:left;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    width: 150px !important;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the table cells have some padding or margin added? Because when I tried your example it works correctly.

Comment: It is not working with me. Can you share what you did

Comment: I did nothing I've just copied your example. Probably you have some other css or maybe I have some. I've used web forms example project form VS 2015.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div style="height: 30px; margin: 0; padding: 0">
<table id="tblHeader" class=""
    style="background-color: #336666; color: white; border-collapse: collapse; height: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td class="col-lg-4" style="text-align:left;width: 50px">
            <span>ID</span>
        </td>
        <td class="col-lg-4" style="text-align:left;width: 150px">
            <span>Employee</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
 <td>
   <div style="height: 360px; overflow: auto;">
    <asp:GridView ID="grdEmp" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    OnRowCommand="grdEmp_RowCommand" ShowHeader="false"
    GridLines="None" Font-Size="Small">
    <Columns>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpID" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
  </asp:GridView>
  </div>
      </td>
                 <td>
        <div style="height: 360px; overflow: auto;">
    <asp:GridView ID="grdEmp" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    OnRowCommand="grdEmp_RowCommand" ShowHeader="false"
    GridLines="None" Font-Size="Small">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpName">
            <ItemStyle CssClass="RowStyle150"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
  </asp:GridView>
  </div>
      </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I have just given idea how to do ... And do also make class changes as per your requirenment